# "Unsupported context type" while creating a controller using MVC controller Entity Framework. MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my code (Model);

```
  public class XpsEntity
  {
    public DbSet<AModel> A { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TModel> T { get; set; }

    public class SDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<XpsEntity>().ToTable("Table1");
            modelBuilder.Entity<XpsEntity>().ToTable("Table2");

        }
    }
```

Is my coding wrong? Because every time I create a controller using MVC Controller Entity Framework. I always get the "Unsupported context type" error.

[Here is the screenshot for adding the controller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXfe3.png)

Comment: Those dbset properties need to be nested in a dbcontext derived class

Comment: How exactly are you "creating a Controller"?

Answer (score 0):

`DbSet` properties need to be nested in a `DbContext` derived class

```
public class SDbContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AModel>().ToTable("Table1");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TModel>().ToTable("Table2");
    }

    public DbSet<AModel> A { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TModel> T { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Update your question with more details of how you have your context and models setup

Comment: When i Create a controller, these are the parameters; Model class: AModel (MvcApplication4.Models), Data context class: XpsEntity(MvcApplication4.Models), Views: Razor.

Comment: Put that in the original post exactly how you did it so we can get a better idea of what you did.Putting them in the comments doesn't really help.